# What is the right Syntax for SetOutPath in NSIS script?

Tags: syntax, scripting, syntax-error, nsis

i want to use `SetOutPath`, but I'm have problem with the Syntax,

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Function InstallIbmGrpFiles

  SetOutPath $ibmGrpFolder

  File /r "/BuildFolder/ ${build.counter}/Bin/IBM_Report" 

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: If you are having syntax problems it helps if you post the compiler error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var ibmGrpFolder
Section
StrCpy $ibmGrpFolder "$programfiles\Ibm\Foo\Bar"
SetOutPath $ibmGrpFolder
DetailPrint "File xyz to $outdir" ; File /r xyz
SectionEnd
```